# Nsight profile experiments not running

Tags: cuda, nsight

I've installed nsight for VS2010 and debugging works well (the card is the Quadro FX 5800 which is supported according to http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nsight-visual-studio-edition-supported-gpus-full-list). However, when I try to run the profiling experiments, the only experiment results that shows up is the occupancy, and the console progress shows the following

```
Nsight: Profiling Kernel test_kernel  
Nsight: Launch Information Experiment ( 1/ 1):.  
Nsight: Experiments complete, total replays needed:  1
```

even though I've requested that all experiments be carried out.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Quadro FX 5800 is based upon the Tesla gt280 chip. Nsight CUDA Profiling has very limited support for Tesla architecture GPUs (different from Tesla brand). In order to collect additional PM counters change the Experiments to Run to Custom. In the experiment selector you can add one or more instances of the Tesla Raw Counter experiment. If you click on the experiment in the selected experiments table in the middle pane the right pane will allow you to choose counters. The counter selector will only allow you to choose counters that can be collected in the same pass. By adding multiple copies of the experiment you can collect all of the counters.